# How to use an older version of Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, visual-studio-mac

Hi i mistakenly upgraded Visual Studio for Mac to 8.5.2 (build 13) which has Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.16.0.13 (Visual Studio Community).

Turns out this doesn't work with XCode 11.3.1 and needs XCode 11.4, which means I will need to upgrade the OS from Mojave to Catalina; i'm not ready to upgrade the OS just yet..

I have tried searching on the Microsoft website, but cant see any obvious links to downgrade or select a different Xamarin.iOS version

How can i roll back the Xamarin.iOS to a version that is compatible with XCode 11.3?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/old-version-xcode

Comment: Hi , which is the previous version of Visual Studio for Mac ?

Comment: Hi - not sure. I ended up just upgrading the MacOS and installing XCode 11.4

Comment: @Steve Here is the previous version of xamrin.iOS , maybe you can install the older version to check.https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases

Comment: I downloaded an older version of xamarin.iOS that works with Mojave and XCode 11.3  here: 
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-12.14.0.114.pkg

Answer (score 4):

To use an older version of Xamarin.iOS you need to download it from a link.
It's very difficult to answer this question, because the answer need a link..
And Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes...

- So, First you need to find the version number of your wanted Xamarin.iOS.

> Here you can see all release Version tags from the official
> xamarin github repository.
> https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/tags

- Then you need to found the Microsoft official patern link from their official download .pkg repository used by Visual Studio.

> The official Microsoft pkg repository : https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg
> The patern link : https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/<framework>/<version>.

- Finally, you need to create your own link regardless you framework and version

> Example:
> Xamarin.iOS: https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/15.4.0.0

But you need to found out your own link by your self.

You can also try from the github

> Xamarin.iOS https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/main/DOWNLOADS.md

Comment: Thank you for the excellent break down for how to find the link, this solved my problem!

Comment: If you search Microsoft.com for 'Xamarin.iOS Release Notes',
That will give you a rundown of requirements (including Xcode version) for a given version of Xamarin.iOS. You can then use this version to start the above.

Example (2022):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/14/14.19